How to install Control Your Tabs plugin for Pluma?
I doubt I should ask here, but it's about Ubuntu anyway. The DE is MATE. I need this plugin:
Control Your Tabs Plugin for Pluma
But the plugins folder is not existing in ~/.config/pluma. In this folder there's only one file with name accels. It contains Pluma accelerator keys. What else? Nothing! When I run Pluma and go to Preferences/Plugins menu, I see that they're there, but where does it bring them and load from? I don't know. It's not ~/.config/pluma for sure. I looked for it nearly in the whole system and found it in /usr/share/pluma! But copying the files there couldn't add this plugin to the list of plugins. Since I used to use Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+PgDn/PgUp, please let me know how can I install this plugin for Pluma or introduce another editor with these hotkeys. Pluma is good, because it supports LTR and RTL at the same time separately for each line.

So why don't you create the plugins-folder? And then extract the files into it?

I certainly had done it and couldn't get a result before I come here and ask the question. I don't know where does Pluma brings the plugins from! They're there, and I find them on disk in /usr/share/pluma, but when I extract this there too, I can't find it in the list of plugins inside the program. It seems that something is missing somewhere else too.
